# Objective-C: Where to see the generated code from setter/getter methods produced with @synthesize?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

I am always a bit confused what the different @property parameters do. So I thought the easiest would be to look what XCode generates from it. For me the best documentation is always the source-code itself. In my naivete I am believing that XCode (respectively the pre-compiler behind it) makes some objective-c code from it. Maybe I am wrong.

This is why I ask where to inspect the generated code from @synthesize ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can’t. There is no precompiler and Xcode doesn’t generate any source code either. The compiler directly generates binary code for those accessors. Those use the runtime library functions `objc_setProperty`  and `objc_getProperty`. You can find a more in-depth explanation [here at Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html).